# What to do when a client is correcting spelling and grammar mistakes that aren't actually mistakes?

Tags: communication, clients

During my last job, on my first project, my boss showed some feedback from a client on a mockup. One of the things the client pointed out was that one of the feedback messages on the mockup had a pretty serious spelling mistake (for those that know their Dutch conjugation: a DT-error).

However, this mistake was not actually a spelling mistake. There was some confusion about the tense I used on the verb in the Dutch message: I used the present perfect, but the client thought I used present simple. I'll post the specific error in a modified form in a comment, in Dutch. I explained this to my boss, who decided that I should just rewrite the sentence to avoid further confusion.

Seeing the recent question about [What to do when a new employee makes basic spelling and grammar mistakes?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/60857/what-to-do-when-a-new-employee-makes-basic-spelling-and-grammar-mistakes) reminded me of this situation, and it got me wondering how this similar situation should be handled. In this case, there isn't actually a mistake, but the client thinks there's one.

What is the appropriate action in this case?

Comment: The error was "Producten zijn voordeliger indien ze in meervouden van 3 worden besteld" (correct version) versus "Producten zijn voordeliger indien ze in meervouden van 3 worden bestelt" (wrong version). The client thought I was using the "onvoltooid tegenwoordige tijd" (present simple tense) of "bestellen", which is written "bestelt", but I was actually using the "voltooid deelword" (present perfect tense) of "bestellen", which is written "besteld".

Comment: Point out to the client that there isn't a mistake.  Actually turning something into a mistake, just to appease the client, won't help anyone, and could actually make you look bad down the road.  Provide proof without sounding condescending.

Comment: Even if the clients corrections aren't correct, the fact that the client thought there was a mistake should cause you to think about how you could prevent future confusion. For every one person that reports an "error" there are a bunch that see it and say nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your client got confused and thought it was a mistake, then other people will make that same assumption, and you don't want something like that to be published. Best to rephrase the whole thing to eliminate any possible ambiguity.